# Conditionally change a join on column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this invalid mysql statement:

```
UPDATE third_party_raw_stock_price AS r
            IF feed_link_column = 'supplier_barcode'
                    JOIN options_new AS o
                        ON o.supplier_barcode = r.supplier_option_code
            END IF
            IF feed_link_column = 'supplier_code'
                    JOIN options_new AS o
                        ON o.supplier_code = r.supplier_option_code
                END  IF
            JOIN third_party_config AS c
                ON SUBSTRING(o.options_id, 3, 2) = c.code
            SET o.price = 9.99, o.cost_price_variation = 3.33, o.stock = 7
            LIMIT 2000
```

How do I rewrite this to dynamically define the options_new join column? I need the join to be either `ON o.supplier_code = r.supplier_option_code` or `ON o.supplier_barcode = r.supplier_option_code`, depending on which is called for by the `third_party_raw_stock_price.third_party_raw_stock_price` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` statement is basically just a boolean test - if the result of the test (however simple or complicated it is) evaluates to `true`, then the records are joined. If it's false, then there's no join.

That means your join condition can be as arbitarily complex as you need it to be, as long as it boils down to a true/false value in the end:

```
SELECT ...
FROM bar
JOIN foo ON (foo.feed = 'barcode' AND foo.supplier = bar.supplier)
            OR 
            (foo.feed = 'code' AND foo.code = bar.code)
```